# Почему при вызове процедуры из пакета ошибка PLS-00905, а как отдельная процедура работает?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Мне дали тестовое задание, частью которого является написание пакета включающего в себя 3 процедуры, которые по входящим параметрам будут выполнять `insert`, `update`, `delete` соответственно. Я написал процедуру для удаления. Вне пакета она успешно работает, а вот при попытке перенести ее в пакет сталкиваюсь с ошибками.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE my_actions AS
   PROCEDURE my_delete
   (table_name in varchar2, idtemp in number);  
END my_actions;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY my_actions AS 
   PROCEDURE my_delete
   (table_name in varchar2, idtemp in number) IS
   BEGIN
     IF table_name = 'contragents' then
       DELETE FROM CONTRAGENTS  WHERE contra_id = idtemp;
       commit;
     ELSIF table_name = 'accounts' then
       DELETE FROM accounts  WHERE account_id = idtemp;
       commit;
     END IF;
   END my_delete;
END my_actions;
```

При попытке обратится к процедуре через:

```
BEGIN
    my_actions.my_delete('contragents', 21);
END;
```

Получаю сообщениe об ошибке PLS-00905:

[image: сообщения об ошибке]

Comment: А почему вы считаете, что что-то не так?

Comment: @0xdb обновил вопрос

Comment: И как вы поняли это сообщение об ошибке? Я понимаю его так: ваш пакет не скомпилировался и вызывать его безполезно.

Comment: @0xdb и почему же он не скомпилировался если скрипт по его инициализации выполнен успешно?

Comment: Не знаю, так утверждает сообщение об ошибке. Почему вы думаете, что он выполнился успешно? Проверте так `select status, object_type from all_objects where owner='SCOTT' and object_name='MY_ACTIONS'`

Comment: @0xdb в результате получил invalid в колонке status

Comment: Значит это было иллюзия, что скрипт выполнился успешно. Смотрите `show errors` после компиляции или средствами вашего IDE.

Comment: Пока нашёл время написатъ ответ на ваш комментарий под ответом вы его удалили. Посмотрите, если ещё актуально.

Answer (score 4):

Такая ошибка возникает, если пакет скомпилировался с ошибками.
Убедиться можно таким запросом:

```sql
select status, object_type 
from all_objects 
where owner='MYSCHEMA' and object_name='TEST1';
```

Посмотреть, какие именно ошибки возникают при компиляции:

```sql
create or replace package test1 as
    procedure a (par int);
end;
/
create or replace package body test1 as
    procedure a (par int) is 
    begin 
        select dummyx from dual;  --здесь ошибка 
    end;
end;
/
show errors package body test1
```

Выведет:

```
Errors for PACKAGE BODY test1:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -------------------------------------------------------------
4/9      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
4/16     PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "DUMMYX": invalid identifier
```

Тотже результат будет получен запросом:

```sql
select line, text
from user_errors
where name = upper ('test1')
order by line;
```

Comment: В PL/SQL Developer окошко с ошибками должно открыватъся автоматически. Также, show errors должно работать в командном окне. И последнее, что всегда будет работать, добавил в ответ.